What were the areas of European countries in 1936 and 1949?
Are there sources (e.g. gazetteers or encyclopedia) that list the precise areas of the different European countries in ~1936 (before Germany's Anschluß with Austria), and again in ~1949 (after the Paris Peace Treaties of 1947)?

This depends a bit on your definition of precision. The most accessable sources would be:

1935-36: Statistical Year-Book of the League of Nations – Table 2: area and population lists the area rounded to 1000 km², for small countries partly with decimal digits (as in Luxembourg: 2.6 * 1000 km², Monaco: 0.002 * 1000 km²...).

1948: United Nations Demographic Yearbook Table 1: Population, area and density lists the area in km².



Thanks! I was hoping for slightly more accuracy (eg rounded to 100 km²) but this will have to do.
